# В проекте открывается только главная страница index.php, на остальных страницах ошибка 404

Tags: php, apache, mvc, xampp

В проекте открывается только главная страница index.php, на остальных страницах ошибка 404. На пк работает всё хорошо. Использую XAMPP, rewrite mod включен, единственное что на ноуте порт-83 а на пк-80, наверное в этом и проблема.

**_htaccess.php**

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

**router.php**

```
<?php

return array(

    //Blog
    'blog/view([0-9]+)' => 'blog/view/$1',
    'blog/about' => 'blog/about',
    'blog/page([0-9]+)' => 'blog/index/$1',
    'blog/category([0-9]+)' => 'blog/viewcategory/$1',

    //Admin
    'admin' => 'admin/index',

    //User
    'user/auth' => 'user/auth',
    'user/register' => 'user/register',
    'user/logout' => 'user/logout',
    'user' => 'user/index',

    //Post
    'post/add' => 'post/add',


    'blog' => 'blog/index',
    '' => 'blog/index', // actionIndex в SiteController

);
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

// FRONT CONTROLLER

// 1. Общие настройки
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();


// 2. Подключение файлов системы
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(ROOT.'/components/Router.php');
require_once(ROOT.'/components/Db.php');
require_once(ROOT.'/components/Autoload.php');
// 4. Вызов Router
$router = new Router();
$router->run();
```

Comment: `_htaccess.php` - это опечатка или реально у тебя в этом файле всё написано?

Comment: Ошибся, _htaccess у меня.

Comment: `_htaccess` или всё же `.htaccess` ?)

Comment: Точно, не заметил:D Спасибо!

Comment: Что, заработало?